# Multi class sparse_categorical_crossentropy TruePositives metric Incompatible shapes: [2,128] vs. [2,64]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to add various simple metrics for each class. `tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives, tf.keras.metrics.Precision ...` This results in crash bellow when last `Dense` layer is two or more.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,128] vs. [2,64]
     [[{{node metrics_12/fp/LogicalAnd}}]]
```

It works if I only use `accuracy` as metric. I am pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental. As I am but a dilettante when it come to TensorFlow and Deep Learning. What am I doing wrong? **How do I get metrics for each class (True/False positives/negatives mainly)?** (Sample code only has 0,1 classes, in real app there are more)

Colab link: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aAz1pfN6ttBp8nU6rZgo8OA_Hwdseyg8

```
#%%

from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple, Optional, Any
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization, CuDNNLSTM, LSTM, Flatten

#%%

# Create random training values for demo purposes.
#
# train_x is [
#   [
#        [0.3, 0.54 ... 0.8],
#        [0.4, 0.6 ... 0.55],
#        ...
#   ],
#   [
#        [0.3, 0.54 ... 0.8],
#        [0.4, 0.6 ... 0.55],
#        ...
#   ],
#   ...
# ]
#
# train_y is corresponding classification of train_x sequences, always 0 or 1
# [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ... 0]

SAMPLES_CNT = 1000

train_x = np.random.rand(SAMPLES_CNT,5,4)
train_y = np.vectorize(lambda x: int(round(x)))(np.random.rand(SAMPLES_CNT))

val_x = np.random.rand(int(SAMPLES_CNT * 0.1),5,4)
val_y = np.vectorize(lambda x: int(round(x)))(np.random.rand(int(SAMPLES_CNT * 0.1)))

#%%

shape = Tuple[int, int]
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=train_x.shape[1:], return_sequences=True, stateful=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=train_x.shape[1:], return_sequences=False, stateful=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

metrics = [
    'accuracy',
    tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(thresholds=[0.5, 0.5], name='fp'),
    tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6),
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=metrics
)

fit = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=(val_x, val_y),
    shuffle=False,
)

for i, val in enumerate(model.metrics_names):
    print(model.metrics_names[i], fit.history[val][:1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But if you do want to know how to do it for multiclass problems, then we need to create custom metrics.

First, I must say that I believe it doesn't make much sense to have these metrics in a categorical problem (only one correct class among many - `'softmax'` + `'categorical_crossentropy'`). Such problem is not "binary", so there isn't really a "positive" and a "negative", but one correct among many.

If you look at it as individual classes and treat each one as a binary class, you'd get something like:

- Every time the model gets a class right, it means 1 TP + 4 TN (notice how many true negatives are there, because there are more than just two outcomes)
- Every time the model gets a class wrong, it means 1 FP + 1 FN + 3 TN

If you add up these numbers, they simply don't make much sense. (Perhaps I'm missing some special method for calculating these for a categorical problem... and yet you can use everything that is below for this too, knowing the above).

Now, on the other hand, you can get good metrics for multiple binary classes (where each class is independent from the others and more than one class can be correct - `'sigmoid'` + `'binary_crossentropy'`).

In this case, you can follow two approaches:

- Get the metrics "per class"
- Average the metrics of all classes somehow (you can see some types of averages here in the [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) documentation)

### Metrics per class

These correspond to the `'binary'` average mode in the sklearn documentation.

#### Alternative 1:

Have each class as an individual model output, in compile, set all these metrics for each of the outputs. Tensorflow will see each output individually and calculate everything without problems.

#### Alternative 2:

This should be done as an individual metric for each class. So we can create a wrapper for this considering the class index.

I'll make some examples. Notice that none of them can be "sparse" because more than one class can be correct, so, in this case, the ground `true` data will have shape `(samples, classes)`, just like the predicted `pred` values.

For every metric, you create a wrapper like this:

```
#class getter
def get_class(true, pred, index):
    #get the class
    true = true[:, index]
    pred = pred[:, index]

    #round pred - you can choose different thresholds
    pred = K.cast(K.greater(pred, 0.5), K.floatx())

    return true, pred

#class wrapper
def some_metric_per_class(class_index):
    def the_actual_metric(true, pred):
        true, pred = get_class(class_index)

        return calculations

    return the_actual_metric
```

A wrapper like this can be used like:

```
metrics = [some_metric_per_class(i) for i in range(n_classes)]
metrics += [some_other_metric_per_class(i) for i in range(n_classes)]
model.compile(metrics = metrics, ...)
```

Here

Now, each of the following metrics **should have their own wrapper** (which I did not write here to avoid unnecessary repetition):

```
def TP(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)
    return K.sum(true * pred)

def FP(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)
    return K.sum(pred * (1 - true))

def TN(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)
    return K.sum((1-true) * (1-pred))

def FN(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)
    return K.sum((1-pred) * true)

def precision(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)

    TP = K.sum(true * pred)
    TP_and_FP = K.sum(pred)

    return K.switch(K.equal(TP_and_FP, 0), 1, TP / TP_and_FP)

def recall(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)

    TP = K.sum(true * pred)
    TP_and_FN = K.sum(true)

    return K.switch(K.equal(TP_and_FN, 0), 1, TP / TP_and_FN)

def AUC(true, pred):
    true, pred = get_class(class_index)

     #We want strictly 1D arrays - cannot have (batch, 1), for instance
    true= K.flatten(true)
    pred = K.flatten(pred)

        #total number of elements in this batch
    totalCount = K.shape(true)[0]

        #sorting the prediction values in descending order
    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(pred, k = totalCount)   
        #sorting the ground truth values based on the predictions above         
    sortedTrue = K.gather(true, indices)

        #getting the ground negative elements (already sorted above)
    negatives = 1 - sortedTrue

        #the true positive count per threshold
    TPCurve = K.cumsum(sortedTrue)

        #area under the curve
    auc = K.sum(TPCurve * negatives)

       #normalizing the result between 0 and 1
    totalCount = K.cast(totalCount, K.floatx())
    positiveCount = K.sum(true)
    negativeCount = totalCount - positiveCount
    totalArea = positiveCount * negativeCount
    return  auc / totalArea
```

[Explanation about AUC](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-transaction-prediction/discussion/82689)

**Important**: precision, recall and AUC will not be exact values, as Keras calculates metrics batchwise and then averages the results of each batch.

### Averaged metrics

These probably only make sense with "precision" and "recall". So I'm doing it for these two.

There is no need for wrappers here, or for individual outputs. The `true` and `pred` data are like in the previous examples, with shape `(samples, classes)`.

Here, we use the same calculations, but now we keep all classes together and decide how to average them.

```
def base_metrics(true, pred):
    #round pred - you can choose different thresholds
    pred = K.cast(K.greater(pred, 0.5), K.floatx())

    TP = K.sum(true * pred, axis=0)
    TP_and_FP = K.sum(pred, axis=0)
    TP_and_FN = K.sum(true, axis=0)

    return TP, TP_and_FP, TP_and_FN

def precision_micro(true, pred):
    TP, TP_FP, TP_FN = base_metrics(true, pred)
    TP = K.sum(TP)
    TP_FP = K.sum(TP_FP)

    return K.switch(K.equal(TP_FP, 0), 1, TP / TP_FP)

def precision_macro(true, pred):
    TP, TP_FP, TP_FN = base_metrics(true, pred)

    precision = K.switch(K.equal(TP_FP, 0), 1, TP / TP_FP)
    return K.mean(precision)
```

You can do the same for `recall_micro` and `recall_macro`, but using `TP_FN` instead of `TP_FP`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! I really appreciate it. I will give it a go. And I will accept the answers as correct in before bounty expires. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these metrics are supposed to work with one class only.

You need `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` and `'binary_crossentropy'`.

Notice that these two problems are exactly the same:

- `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`, with `loss='binary_crossentropy'`
- `Dense(2, activation='softmax')`, with `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply I see your point. What about if I have multiple classes and I would like to know let's say recall and true / false positives for each class. What would be the most straight froward way ? I though thats what metrics would provide out of the box. What am I missing ? (Thank you !)

Comment: @stringCode,  In your problem you don't need multiclasses. A `Dense(2, activation='softmax')` with `'categorical_crossentropy'` is **exactly the same as** a `Dense(1, activation=`sigmoid`)` with `'binary_crossentropy'`. As for the ground truth data (targets), you don't need to change anything. Values 0 represent the first class, values 1 represent the second class.